# How do I calculate group total?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query which returns the below from joining two tables:

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Type          |  Price          |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Music         |  19.99          |
| Music         |   3.99          |
| Music         |  21.55          |
| Toy           |  89.95          |
| Toy           |   3.99          |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

My problem is how do I group the products by type, so that it displays a single product type and total price for each product type? For example:

```
Music | 45.53
Toy   | 93.94
```

and so on.

Comment: It would help us modify your query if you showed us the query...

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. the query is very messy and joins three tables in a somewhat complicated manner. Is there anyway to get the desired result with just php e.g. display a product type from the array, check to see if next product types is same as displayed product type; if so add price to existing product type. Else display new product type. Suggested approaches below would be suitable if it were just a single table query. I can post the query as soon as I get a chance to if it is still needed. Can't access it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it at last.

```
// Get the sum
$group = array();
foreach($rows as $r){
  $group[$r->type] = $group[$r->Type] + $r->Price;
}

// Display
foreach($group as $type=>$price){
  echo "Type:".$type." Price: ".$price;
}
```

original post here: [Group results in subgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751597/php-group-results-in-subgroups)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT type, SUM(price) FROM table_name GROUP BY (type)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
mysql> select type, round(sum(price),2) sum from storage group by type;
+-------+-------+
| type  | sum   |
+-------+-------+
| Music | 45.53 |
| Toy   | 93.94 |
+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

Comment: @Matmarbon Totally got it mixed up. Fixed it now.

Comment: Even though, the -1 is not mine :/