# Group results in subgroups

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

I have been trying to get the subgroup total of the data below using the method in the accepted answer here: [how to group result in subgroups in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707613/how-to-group-result-in-subgroups-in-php), but to no avail. Somebody please help.

I want this:

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Type          |  Price          |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Music         |  19.99          |
| Music         |   3.99          |
| Music         |  21.55          |
| Toy           |  89.95          |
| Toy           |   3.99          |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

displayed as this:

```
Music | 45.53
Toy   | 93.94
```

in group and subtotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```php
// Get the sum
$group = array();
foreach($rows as $r){
  $group[$r->type] = $group[$r->Type] + $r->Price;
}

// Display
foreach($group as $type=>$price){
  echo "Type:".$type." Price: ".$price;
}
```

Comment: Genius you are Dipu! Many thanks guys, hopefully these'll help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it directly in MySQL when you perform the query (if possible):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Type, SUM(Price) as Total FROM table_name GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Niklas, but the query is very complicated and joins three tables. It's been a struggle to get it to return the result as above. Grouping directly from mysql hasn't worked.

Comment: I see. Could you perhaps show the structure of the array you get from the SQL query listed in your post? You can use print_r($array) or var_dump($array) for that. It will be much easier to answer your question if the array structure is given :)

Answer (score 1):

You could select the sum of the prices, then group the subtotals by type. I used this SQL statement in a PHP script;

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Total, Type FROM Table GROUP BY Type
```

I then executed the SQL statement and echoed the results in a simple foreach loop. It appears to work fine with me.